# How to find the polar coordinate angle of the tangent of any point on an ellipse?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

I have an ellipse centered at 0,0 with a height of 75 and a width of 150. Now let say I know both the x and y and also the angle of a point on the circumference of the ellipse. I want to know what the angle of the point tangent to ellipse is relative to polar coordinates.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric equations for a central ellipse (aligned with the X & Y axes) are
$$x = a\cos(\theta)$$
$$y = b\sin(\theta)$$

where $a$ and $b$ are the "radii" of the ellipse on the X & Y axes, respectively; in other words, $a$ and $b$ are the lengths of the semimajor and semiminor axes of the ellipse.

However, $\theta$ is *not* the central angle of the ellipse, it's the central angle of the auxiliary circles associated with the ellipse. In astronomy, it's known as the [eccentric anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly). Here's a diagram, courtesy of Wikipedia (click the image for an SVG version):
[image: Eccentric anomaly diagram]

> The eccentric anomaly of point P is the angle E. The center of the ellipse is point C, and the focus is point F.

The blue circle provides the X coordinate of P, and the green circle provides its Y coordinate.

As Intelligenti pauca mentions in the comments, the polar angle $\phi$ can be calculated using:

$$\tan\phi={y\over x}={b\over a}\tan\theta$$

Differentiating the previous equations for $x$ & $y$,
$$\begin{align}
dx & = -a\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\\
dy & = b\cos(\theta)\,d\theta
\end{align}$$

Therefore,
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{b\cos(\theta)}{-a\sin(\theta)}$$
and that's the slope of the required tangent. So the angle $\alpha$ that tangent makes with the (positive) X axis is
$$\alpha = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b\cos(\theta)}{-a\sin(\theta)}\right)$$

Comment: What is theta? And is a and be the radii of the ellipse?

Comment: @drstuggels Warning: $\theta$ defined here is NOT the polar angle. The polar angle is $\phi$ given by $$\tan\phi={y\over x}={b\over a}\tan\theta.$$

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks for picking up that stupid error. (I have no idea why I wrote that, I've known this stuff for *years*). I've fixed it now.