# Rotated ellipse - calculate points with an absolute angle

Tags: rotations, parametric, elliptic-equations

I can draw ellipses nicely with this formula

```
 alpha = 0-360 °
 x: = width * Cos (alpha)
 y: = height * Sin (alpha)
```

The first point (alpha = 0 °) is to the right of the center point:

[image]

and rotate the ellipse at the same time with this formula:

```
 alpha = 0-360 °
 beta = 20 ° inclination
 x: = width * Cos (alpha) * Cos (beta) - height * Sin (alpha) * Sin (beta)
 y: = width * Cos (alpha) * Sin (beta) + height * Sin (alpha) * Cos (beta)
```

Source: [What is the parametric equation of a rotated Ellipse (given the angle of rotation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645689/what-is-the-parametric-equation-of-a-rotated-ellipse-given-the-angle-of-rotatio)

When you turn, you also turn the coordinate system of the
ellipse. The point alpha = 0 is now 20 ° below the
center.

[image]

I'm trying to get points in the rotated ellipse with absolute angles.
The green dot.

Maybe someone knows how to do it.

Comment: Your rotation is opposite to mine. I suspect that you're using an upside down coordinate system, where Y coordinates increase down the page, which is very common in computer graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to calculate the value of $\alpha$ where the ellipse crosses the positive X axis.

We have
$$x = w\cos\alpha\cos\beta - h\sin\alpha\sin\beta$$
$$y = w\cos\alpha\sin\beta + h\sin\alpha\cos\beta$$

Let $y=0$
$$h\sin\alpha\cos\beta=-w\cos\alpha\sin\beta$$
$$\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=\frac{-w\sin\beta}{h\cos\beta}$$
That is,
$$\tan\alpha=\frac{-w}{h}\tan\beta$$

In computer code, we should use the two argument form of the arctangent function to make sure we get the correct quadrant, eg

```
alpha = atan2(-w*sin(beta), h*cos(beta))
```

So $\sin\alpha$ and $\sin\beta$ have opposite signs, and $\cos\alpha$ and $\cos\beta$ have the same sign.

Now we have to check that $x$ is positive at that $\alpha$ value. We substitute
$$\sin\alpha=(-w/h) \cos\alpha\tan\beta$$
into our equation for $x$:
$$x=w\cos\alpha\cos\beta - h(-w/h)\cos\alpha\tan\beta\sin\beta$$
$$x=w\cos\alpha(\cos\beta + \tan\beta\sin\beta)$$
which simplifies to
$$x=w\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta}$$

Now $\cos\alpha$ and $\cos\beta$ have the same sign, so $x$ is positive, and our $\alpha$ value *does*, in fact, give us the point where the ellipse crosses the positive X axis.

We can now add that value as an offset to our parameter.

Let
$$\delta=\arctan\left(\frac{-w\sin\beta}{h\cos\beta}\right)$$
And
$$x = w\cos(\alpha+\delta)\cos\beta - h\sin(\alpha+\delta)\sin\beta$$
$$y = w\cos(\alpha+\delta)\sin\beta + h\sin(\alpha+\delta)\cos\beta$$
are our new parametric equations.

---

Here's some Sage / Python code that uses those equations to plot the ellipse, and several dots with $\alpha$ in the range $[0, \pi/2]$.

```
@interact
def main(w=3, h=4, b=20):
    b *= pi / 180
    cb, sb = cos(b), sin(b)
    d = atan2(-w * sb, h * cb)

    def fx(t):
        return w * cos(t+d) * cb - h * sin(t+d) * sb

    def fy(t):
        return w * cos(t+d) * sb + h * sin(t+d) * cb

    P = parametric_plot([fx, fy], (0, 2*pi))
    P += point([(fx(t), fy(t))
        for t in srange(0, 9*pi/16, pi/16)], color="red")
    show(P)
```

Here's a [live version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNkMFqwzAQRO_5iiEnyVaI45bSFgT9hNxDKZIsJ4JEMpKK07_vSjal9NS9LNqdeTvozflsozJ5M9gRN-U8m-WDwEU-CmjZd_x1AyqNRmJy2OPw3NWJ0QJJQ8KExDSnB3k1r7uBxior37PdjIZkBKRuaL3s6dZ4Z3mFl4o2f0aPIi_A3A68OrCr1gJfZ0n_gnz9A0Ip278Qs0KOlHRSUd1sjs58TNeQ2Wm8CyK_C7BOoG8mx_kqbkkd6MvYidX8YknAfxKMISLDeaSo_NkWwAsB9ocngdo4YU24hii30Q7bxZkuYWZH_g3DNmad&lang=sage), running on the SageMathCell server.

And here's the output, with the default parameters.

[image: Rotated ellipse]

Here's an [updated version of the script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNkE-P0zAUxO_9FE_hYjuuki0rBEiROHHeI9IKofhPN5a6TrBdmnx7xo7pIk7kYmXe888z88X5ZMOo08HYM72OzrPb8F7SNDxKUsOp558PhE-RGGhx1NHDx74oWkmKigbSc2SK4wd3FS8zA3lMoz-x440E1gDEqev4HX113hAWXqxP2KRvNK4u7lwDlKlcU7lmv7hBPt5EVAIbLU1CK6FNGa37SJfREaN4HwWM4s-Q2CpW3NrEttPSdLe5SVp3cQlohDXVWyPJszQJhO4WBzONsS_B2tjww54UrZ1XlmpN5TmbrsFTDp4jpNbwkj27ymUgTtWi-guy_QcEfbf_QnSFPCHMMobx1abg9I_lMif2fF4lyN8lsV7SSSACr8sttucc9ZkV_3J3wO8OznOgRM5TDLmLDPgEQPfwQVI5OLB6vsxhaII1zX7zKukXjADZA9m_PXZx3uKtK1pYu5C3jrR1AUvQ2j9aW7Q3cO7aV3Sc5ht74r8BjHCzuA==&lang=sage) which calculates the angle of the tangent to the ellipse where it crosses the +X axis. It also draws the tangent line.

---

Note that $\alpha$, is only indirectly related to the central polar angle of the ellipse. It's actually the polar angle of the two auxiliary circles associated with this parameterization, which have radii $w$ and $h$. In astronomy, this parameter is known as the [eccentric anomaly](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly).

Comment: FWIW, here's another answer of mine about eccentric anomaly: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4086900/207316

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. that helps me a lot, hopefully others too;) greetings

Comment: hello, in my replica
`
     w = 3.0;
     h = 4.0;
     b = 20.0;
     b * = Pi / 180.0;
     cb, sb = Cos (b), Sin (b);
     d = Atan2(-w * sb, h * cb);
     for t = 0.0; t <= 30.0; t + = 3.0 {
         x = w * Cos (t + d) * cb - h * Sin (t + d) * sb;
         y = w * Cos (t + d) * cb - h * Sin (t + d) * sb;
         // print dot ...
     }
`    
every second point is printed 180 degrees offset. t = 0 left, t = 3 right ... five point left, five points right. I can't find my bug. Is there a condition that I missed? Thank you & best regards

Comment: These formulae come from the standard identities: $$\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$$ & $$\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$$

Comment: oh, my for loops was wrong. mixed up radians and degrees. shame on me ... 
now it looks fine. I use the language Go, has it own feature ... I have tried to
make it uniform. I have also seen your other post regarding tangent. 
Is it possible to use this function also for absolute angles? By simply
adding "d" `(atan2(-w * sb, h * cb))` like you have done it above? Anyway,
thank you very much

Comment: I just mean the solution in this thread ;) I thought it is called absolute and relative angles...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124025/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-absimon).